# What is the most solid option for BLOB storage?

Tags: database, blob, data-storage

I have to develope something to hold blob's. I have a various options but have a hard time choosing. What is needed is for the user to upload documents in the form of images mostly. I need to make it secure. I would like some speed though it's not a prerequisite. The size of the uploaded images/documents will "probably" not be too much of an issue.

The options I have found so far are:

1. SQL FileStream
2. Azure Storage
3. HDD
4. Other cloud services like Amazon etc.

I am not too fond of the cloud since it will be somewhat sensitive data and I am not liking the price model. Not saying it's bad it's just a personal preference.

When it comes to FileStream I have no idea, I have been recommended both for and against it. Does it really work?

HDD, well yeah it's meant to store things but now I need to code for both Database and HDD. I am not overly fond of that tight coupling.

Are there any other suggestions on how to store stuff? Can I get some comments on the options I mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be either Azure or Amazon

Answer (score 1):

`FileStream` just ends up going to the HDD. The only thing that gets stored in the DB is a reference to the file. You can replace the file with different content, and SQL server will never know.

I would personally just use the HDD, that's your best bet, if you want full control over the files.